# Multiple Entites(Post & Product) to have common entity(Comment) as ICollection

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

In my project there are 2 classes (this will increase) `Post` and `Product`, both can have comments below is the structure i have created but its no working

I have created an interface for entities which can have comments

```
public interface ICommentable
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}
```

`Post` and `Product` entities may have comments

```
public class Post : ICommentable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}

public class Product : ICommentable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Rate { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

Comment Entity Itself

```
public class Comment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public ICommentable Item{ get; set; }
}
```

Data Contxet

```
public class DataBaseContext:DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity framework doesn't support interfaces so it is your first problem. The second problem is that navigation property cannot be normally "polymorphic" = you need separate navigation property (and FK) for every `ICommentable` you want to relate to your `Comment`:

```
public class Comment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public Post Post { get; set; }

    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

The only scenario where something similar can work is mapped inheritance but it would force your `Post` and `Product` to inherit from mapped base entity and this inheritance will be reflected in the database. In such case you can have separate table for base entity and this table can have relation to `Comment` (instead of derived tables).

When working with relations always think about the way how would you done it in the database. Your classes mapped by EF must follow similar rules.

Comment: The problem with codes shown by u is that its dedicated for 2 entities  only  but in my real situation there are more than 20 entities  that may be commentable that means i have to create 40 more properties in `comment` entity (eg: Blog, BlogId and so on). I am planning to use mapped inheritance as you have written it too. What are the disadvantages of mapped inheritance??

Comment: So back to my last paragraph. How would you done it in the database without having 20 FKs? Mapped inheritance will make all your derived types part of single entity set. It can have some impact on query performance because EF sometimes make horrible queries when querying part of inheritance hierarchy. Also you will have to keep unique PK in the base entity - mapped inheritance forbid having two records from different derived types with the same PK value.